# Recover organisational information from SSL cert / key

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, openssl

I am administering an RHEL 6.6 server which I inherited from an admin the company no longer has contact with. I need to replace the SSL cert, for which some information regarding the physical organisation is needed:

```
$ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -keyout example.com.key -out example.com.csr
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
..........+++
.........................................................+++
writing new private key to 'example.com.key'
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:US
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:New Jersey
Locality Name (eg, city) []:Salem
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:International Widgets
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:example.com
Email Address []:foo@example.com

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:
An optional company name []:International Widgets
```

**Given the extant  SSL cert or key, how might I recover the organisational information used?** I'm not sure how critical it is that this information match what was there before, but I would rather be safe than sorry. Unfortunately, this being an online business there is no single physical address to simply use, and the business is split between four owners none of whom know whose information was in the original cert.

**Maybe it really doesn't matter if I simply answer everything "foobar", but I cannot assume that.**

I tried using the `openssl` tool to get the information, but nothing of interest came up:

```
$ openssl x509 -text -in example.com.crt
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1xxxxxxxxxx1 (0x4xxxxxxxb)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=GoDaddy.com, Inc., OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository, CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=07969287
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug 11 12:16:01 2014 GMT
            Not After : Aug 11 12:16:01 2015 GMT
        Subject: OU=Domain Control Validated, CN=*.example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    ...
                    7d:05:34:ac:7f:e2:c2:13:d3:56:9e:4e:fb:57:e3:
                    ...
                    16:cb
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.godaddy.com/gds1-112.crl

            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.16.840.1.114413.1.7.23.1
                  CPS: http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.godaddy.com/
                CA Issuers - URI:http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/gd_intermediate.crt

            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:FD:AC:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:CC:E7

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:*.example.com, DNS:example.com
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                1C:EB:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:F0:2F
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         ...
         43:fd:fb:92:8b:ee:82:0e:63:db:4f:dc:66:46:0f:fb:ac:de:
         ...
         d8:a5:89:eb
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
ODcwHhcNMTQwODIxMTAyNjA2WhcNMTUwODIxMTAyNjA2WjA8MSEwHwYDVQQLExhE
xZHYpYnr
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Most SSL certificate providers completely ignore everything in those fields except CN (which is your domain name).

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Thank you Michael, is there any way to confirm that?

Comment: Ask the provider.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the correct info by using this command: (note that you'll want to use the CSR, and not the CRT)

```
openssl x509 -in example.com.csr -noout -text
```

Towards the top of the output you'll see the Subject information.

Example:

```
[user@server ssl]# openssl req -in example.com.csr -noout -text
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 0 (0x0)
        Subject: C=US, ST=State, L=City, O=Default Company Ltd, CN=example.com/emailAddress=email@email.comm
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
```

Comment: Very good, thank you! One problem, it seems that I don't actually have the CSR, just the key and cert. I'll edit the question to clarify that, as I thought that we still had the CSR.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's not a way to pull that info from the certificate itself (hopefully someone will come along and correct me).  In that case I think your only option might be to contact the issuer of the certificate.  If you've got an account with them, you should be able to get a copy of the request or at least verify the info.

Comment: I'll see if GoDaddy kept the old CSR. If nobody shows how to recover the info from a cert or key, I will accept this answer. Thank you Alex, and welcome to serverfault!

Comment: On all CSRs that I try, I get this type of error: `139842060777120:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE`. I use a line similar to this to create the CSR: `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -rsa256 -keyout site.key -out site.csr`

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned earlier, the importance of certificate detail accuracy tends to vary from vendor to vendor.  The verification process also depends on the *type* of certificate you're getting.  For example, "Extended Validation" certificates have a more rigorous approval process.  In any event, I think it's good practice to make the information as accurate as possible.

If you still have the previously signed certificate, you can absolutely use the openssl command @Alex suggested.

Here's a variation of it: `openssl x509 -in example.crt -text -noout | grep -i "Subject:"`

That should isolate just the `Subject:` details of the cert and show the attributes.  For example, you could get output like:

```
 Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=San Francisco, O=Example Company, OU=IT Services, CN=somewebaddress.example.com
```

Comment: You can also use `-subject` option instead of `-text | grep -i "Subject:"`